# Calculate characteristic frequency from atomic polarizability

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, dielectric

With Lorentz model, the plasma frequency can be calculated from electron density

$$\omega_p=\sqrt\frac{4\pi N e^2}{3m}$$

But I also found in this [paper](http://web.science.uu.nl/ITF/Teaching/2010/Maarten%20Verdult.pdf#page=10) that it could also be calculated from atomic polarizability (Eqn 2.2)

$$\omega_p=\sqrt\frac{e^2}{\alpha_0 m\epsilon_0}$$

What is the equation derived from? What are its assumptions? Thanks!

P.S. the results from the two equations seem to be usually inconsistent, so I think they should be applied to difference scenarios.

Comment: Can you please provide the page number, or even better, link us to the page number

Comment: @Cicero Did it!